# OpenCV - warpPerspective

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to use the function "warpPerspective" with OpenCV 3.0. I'm using this example:

http://answers.opencv.org/question/98110/how-do-i-stitch-images-with-two-different-angles/

I have to create a ROI on the right side of the first image and another one on the left side of the second image. Use ORB to extract and compute descriptions and match these ones. I didn't changed much of the original code. Just the ROI.

The problem is that every image that i try to warp the perspective comes out like this:

[image: warped image]

I already tried with multiple pairs of images and the problem persists.

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

Mat img1 = imread("image2.jpg");
Mat img2 = imread("image1.jpg");
namedWindow("I2", WINDOW_NORMAL); namedWindow("I1", WINDOW_NORMAL);

Ptr<ORB> o1 = ORB::create();
Ptr<ORB> o2 = ORB::create();
vector<KeyPoint> pts1, pts2;
Mat desc1, desc2;
vector<DMatch> matches;

Size s = img1.size();
Size s2 = img2.size();

Rect r1(s.width - 200, 0, 200, s.height);
//rectangle(img1, r1, Scalar(255, 0, 0), 5);
Rect r2(0, 0, 200, s2.height);
//rectangle(img2, r2, Scalar(255, 0, 0), 5);
Mat mask1 = Mat::zeros(img1.size(), CV_8UC1);
Mat mask2 = Mat::zeros(img1.size(), CV_8UC1);
mask1(r1) = 1;
mask2(r2) = 1;
o1->detectAndCompute(img1, mask1, pts1, desc1);
o2->detectAndCompute(img2, mask2, pts2, desc2);
BFMatcher descriptorMatcher(NORM_HAMMING, true);

descriptorMatcher.match(desc1, desc2, matches, Mat());
// Keep best matches only to have a nice drawing.
// We sort distance between descriptor matches
Mat index;
int nbMatch = int(matches.size());
Mat tab(nbMatch, 1, CV_32F);
for (int i = 0; i<nbMatch / 2; i++)
{
    tab.at<float>(i, 0) = matches[i].distance;
}
sortIdx(tab, index, SORT_EVERY_COLUMN + SORT_ASCENDING);
vector<DMatch> bestMatches;
vector<Point2f> src, dst;
for (int i = 0; i < nbMatch / 2; i++)
{
    int j = index.at<int>(i, 0);
    cout << pts1[matches[j].queryIdx].pt << "\t" << pts2[matches[j].trainIdx].pt << "\n";
    src.push_back(pts1[matches[j].queryIdx].pt + Point2f(0, img1.rows)); // necessary offset 
    dst.push_back(pts2[matches[j].trainIdx].pt);
}
cout << "\n";
Mat h = findHomography(src, dst, RANSAC);
Mat result;
cout << h << endl;

warpPerspective(img2, result, h.inv(), Size(3 * img2.cols + img1.cols, 2 * img2.rows + img1.rows));

imshow("I1", img1);
imshow("I2", img2);

Mat roi1(result, Rect(0, img1.rows, img1.cols, img1.rows));
img1.copyTo(roi1);
namedWindow("I3", WINDOW_NORMAL);
imshow("I3", result);
imwrite("result.jpg", result);
waitKey();
return 0;
```

Does that comes from bad matches? Am i missing something? Since i'm kind of new to this topic, any help or ideas would be really appreciated.

Comment: May be use non inverted homography matrix ?

Comment: Problem persists. The image now stretchs on the other side of the first image with same aspect.

Comment: i just want to say: http://answers.opencv.org is open and active. i think the best way for solving your problem is asking @LBerger ( author of code). if you did not get an answer then you can try other ways.

Comment: looks like wrong homography values, probably from wrong matches

Answer (score 4):

Here's the quick things you need to check when your warp perspective is not working-

1. Did you select the right points in both the images ?
   Reason: You need to choose exactly the same points that correspond to each 
   other when finding a perspective transform. Unrelated points ruin it.
2. Are your points in right order in the array ? 
   R: You need to put them in the right corresponding order in both the source and 
   destination before passing to findhomography.
3. Are you passing then in the right order to findHomography ? Try switching in 
   case you are not sure. So that is doesn't reverse warp it

Those are the mistakes i did when i first used it. Now if you see your images, there's a little part overlapping in both the images. You need to be more careful over there. Your rect mask might be the fault.

Comment: I kinda did it. But everytime i execute the program, it results in different matches. Sometimes it works and sometimes don't. There should exist some kind of pattern, right?

Comment: Ya, that's fair. If stitching images is only what you want, did you try manually choosing the points to stitch ? Like you can choose with mouse the points and stitch them

Comment: Sadly i have to make the features detection automatic. I would really appreciate your help. I already know how to develop a drag-and-drop to make a ROI. I just can't understand the pattern the detector uses.